# How to hold correct values in EditText in a RecyclerView ,when scrolls value changes?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerview` with images and titles.I added for all `position` `EditText`, but when I write on a EditText the same text is written on another EditText in another position.Why?

My Code:

```
     public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.VideoHolder> {

            private ArrayList<Video> mData;
            private ArrayList<Video> mData2;
            private Fragment mACtivity;
            private OnImageClickListener onImageClickListener;
            String iddd;
            int id_item;
            ArrayList<Integer> arrayListInteger;
            int c;
            String d = "";
            ArrayList<String> arrayListString;
            int j;
            Context context;
            ArrayList<String> arrayList;
            String []mDataset=new String[100];
            Context mContext;

            public VideoAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
                mDataset = myDataset;
            }
  @Override
    public VideoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.anteprima_list_item, parent, false);

        return new VideoHolder(view);
    }
          @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoHolder holder, final int position) {

          holder.tw.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        mDataset[position] = s.toString();
                        Log.d("DATA" + position + "0", s.toString());
                    }
                });

    public class VideoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            ImageView videoImageView;
            TextView videoNameTextView;
            TextView subtitleVideoTextView;
            TextView dateTextView;
            LinearLayout linearlayout;
            ImageView iv;
            Button button;
            EditText tw;
            TextView tt;
            ListView lw;


            //ImageView preferiti_imageview;

            ToggleButton preferiti;



            public VideoHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                linearlayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById((R.id.linearlayout));

                videoImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoImageView);
                videoNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoNameTextView);
                subtitleVideoTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitleVideoTextView);
                dateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
                iv=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareButton2);
                //preferiti_imageview=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.preferiti_imageview);
                preferiti=(ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.preferiti);
                button=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

                tw=(EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.et);
                tt=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_entry_title);
                lw=(ListView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
                //MyTextWatcher textWatcher = new MyTextWatcher(tw);
               // tw.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);


            }


            public void setTitolo(String titolo) {
                videoNameTextView.setText(titolo);
            }

            public void setSottoTitolo(String sottotitolo) {
                subtitleVideoTextView.setText(sottotitolo);
            }
            public void setCommento(ArrayList<String> commento) {
                tt.setText((CharSequence) commento);
            }

            public void setData(String data) {
                dateTextView.setText(data);
            }


        }
            }
        }
```

My code doesn't work!
Someone can help me?
Thank you.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->




        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/videoImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/videoNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Restaurant Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitleVideoTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Some address placeholder"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <!--  <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/shareButton2"
              android:layout_gravity="left"
              android:src="@mipmap/facebook_share"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
              android:onClick="shareTutorialonFB">

          </ImageView>
  -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Get direction: 2km away"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shareButton2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@mipmap/facebook_share"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

        </ImageView>
      <!-- <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/preferiti_imageview"
            android:src="@mipmap/preferiti"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@mipmap/facebook_share"

            >

        </ImageView>-->
        <ToggleButton

            android:id="@+id/preferiti"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="76dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textOff="aggiungi ai preferiti"
            android:textOn="togli dai preferiti"

            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="Multiline EditText by XML layout"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:background="#d3d7b6"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="commenta"
            />
       <!-- <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>-->
       <!-- <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp" >
        </TextView>-->
  <!--  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
       &lt;!&ndash; <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
        </ListView>&ndash;&gt;
    </LinearLayout>-->

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: where i have to add holder.tw.setText?

Comment: I've made an answer below, you should init the value of `EditText` every time before list item shows to user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `TextWatcher` in `onBindViewHolder` is not recommended it will also lag your UI

Instead, use it in your `onCreateViewHolder`

Update `onBindViewHolder` to

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.customEditTextListener.setPosition(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.mEditText.setText(mDataset[holder.getAdapterPosition()]);
    }
```

in `onCreateViewHolder`

```
@Override
    public VideoAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                  int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.xxxxx, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v, new CustomEditTextListener());

        return vh;
    }
```

`ViewHolder` to

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public EditText mEditText;
    public CustomEditTextListener customEditTextListener;

    public ViewHolder(View v, CustomEditTextListener customEditTextListener) {
        super(v);

        this.mEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.item_edit_text);
        this.customEditTextListener = customEditTextListener;
        this.mEditText.addTextChangedListener(customEditTextListener);
    }
}
```

CustomEditTextListener

```
private class CustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher {
    private int position;

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        mDataset[position] = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me? Please? i have the same problem with listview.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48564984/how-to-hold-correct-position-of-listview-in-a-recyclerview-when-scrolls-value-c?noredirect=1#comment84126953_48564984

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to create HashMap integer for saving the item position and the string to save the edittext value .. and in onbindView .. you have to get the text from the hashmap and set it to the edit text.

Answer (score 0):

1. add `holder.tw.setText(mDataset[position]);` at the first line of method `onBindViewHolder()`
2. move the `TextWatcher` into `ViewHolder`

Full code:

```
public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.VideoHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Video> mData;
    private ArrayList<Video> mData2;
    private Fragment mACtivity;
    private OnImageClickListener onImageClickListener;
    String iddd;
    int id_item;
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayListInteger;
    int c;
    String d = "";
    ArrayList<String> arrayListString;
    int j;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    String []mDataset=new String[100];
    Context mContext;


    public VideoAdapter(Context context, String[] myDataset) {
        mContext = context;
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }
    @Override
    public VideoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.anteprima_list_item, parent, false);

        return new VideoHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tw.setText(mDataset[position]);  // <-- reset text of EditText every time
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }

    public class VideoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView videoImageView;
        TextView videoNameTextView;
        TextView subtitleVideoTextView;
        TextView dateTextView;
        LinearLayout linearlayout;
        ImageView iv;
        Button button;
        EditText tw;
        TextView tt;
        ListView lw;


        //ImageView preferiti_imageview;

        ToggleButton preferiti;



        public VideoHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            linearlayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById((R.id.linearlayout));

            videoImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoImageView);
            videoNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoNameTextView);
            subtitleVideoTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitleVideoTextView);
            dateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
            iv=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareButton2);
            //preferiti_imageview=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.preferiti_imageview);
            preferiti=(ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.preferiti);
            button=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

            tw=(EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.et);
            tt=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_entry_title);
            lw=(ListView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
            //MyTextWatcher textWatcher = new MyTextWatcher(tw);
            // tw.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

            tw.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {  // <-- move the TextWatcher here 
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    int position = getLayoutPosition();

                    mDataset[position] = s.toString();
                    Log.d("DATA" + position + "0", s.toString());
                }
            });
        }


        public void setTitolo(String titolo) {
            videoNameTextView.setText(titolo);
        }

        public void setSottoTitolo(String sottotitolo) {
            subtitleVideoTextView.setText(sottotitolo);
        }
        public void setCommento(ArrayList<String> commento) {
            tt.setText((CharSequence) commento);
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            dateTextView.setText(data);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full class of `VideoAdapter `?

Comment: I need to check the `VideoAdapter.VideoHolder `

Comment: When you type something in the `EditText`, the log `Log.d("DATA" + position + "0", s.toString());` is print correctly?

Comment: i get the position where i get the same values, while i have to get only one position

Comment: Please post the "full" `VideoAdapter` again, there's missing method `onCreateViewHolder()` and post the item layout you inflated

Comment: i just posted it!